# Who painted this image of an alternate history battle in Paris with modern day weaponry?

Tags: image-identification

I'm trying to find the original artist who painted this "alternate history" image:

[image]

I've tried google reverse image search, tin eye and yandex and have gone through many pages of search results, but I can't find any link to the original artist, or even anyone on an artwork site like deviant art who claims to have painted it.

I'm not sure if it's from a game, some cover art, book art or anything else (film?). Most sites that host it seem to refer to it as some sort of WWIII image.

Can anyone tell me who was the original artist who painted this image? Alternatively, are there any other good methods apart from the ones I've already suggested for me to track down the owner, or at the very least find out what it was originally used for (i.e. if it's from a game, then which game)?

Comment: Includes "painted" too, that it seems to be a collage of alienated photographs? For me the faces of the soldiers in front look to detailed to be drawn from scratch, more like processed photographs...

Comment: Do you think so? It looks like one complete image painted by one artist to me (but I'm no expert).

Comment: For the record, this image is part of a series of "future war" pictures, which means that it's firmly on-topic.

Comment: I found a version from 2013: https://www.puzzcore.com/pzl/130803AOI7 - Thus this image is from 2013 or older. Looking for similar art of the time I also stumbled into Spiros Karkavelas a.k.a Aisxos (admin of Concept-ArtMasters on deviant art). By the way another artist I found by similar means: Jae Cheol Park. After going over their galleries I did not find this exact picture.

Comment: @Theraot Thank you, I also found Spiros the same way but didn't see that exact image in his gallery, so I doubt he painted it (even though his style is very similar).

Comment: OK. I spent waaay too much time working this out. In the end I used Tineye and then googled about a hundred image names until I spotted the word Zootfly. From there it was just a case of looking at about thirty concept artists who've worked for them until I found one whose work looked similar. :-)

Comment: Wow, I really appreciate your persistence! Oh BTW I just thought I'd add that I contacted Spiros and he confirmed that he isn't the artist.

Comment: @Arj - You might want to let him know that it's been solved :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The artist is **[Ivan Khivrenko](https://ilustra.co.uk/portfolio/ivan-hivrenko)**, formerly Concept Artist for Zootfly Studio. The image was part of a set of unused concepts for an game called World War III and is titled *'Увидеть Париж и не умереть'* (*'See Paris and Not Die'*)

You can see an article [here](http://old.mirf.ru/Articles/art2545.htm), in which Ivan talks about his creative process. There's also a link to another artwork evidently relating to the same game.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer after so long! From the translation of your second link it does appear as though Ivan is the artist, but I'm curious why that image doesn't appear on his portfolio (your first link)?

Comment: @Arj - His portfolio seems to consist of works that he has drawn independently, rather than for work. Or, presumably, where he holds the sole licence to them

Comment: Thanks, and nice work ;)

Comment: @Arj - [What can I say, except 'you're welcome'?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wrSsIVqHpM)